# composer installation on wamp in window 7 OS

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I followed the steps in this website:

http://www.wikihow.com/Install-Laravel-Framework-in-Windows

**But it's not working on the instructions. Step #11**

It displays like this in the command window:

> The "https"//packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be downloaded: php _network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. failed to open stream: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known.

I'm stuck on this, please help me on this. Thank you.

Comment: Is the quote after https a typo?

Answer (score 0):

I never managed to get it working in WAMP server. I took my shot with XAMPP. Enormous gigantous (almost 1 GB), but heck yeah, it works!

So, try that, everything should work smoothly.

https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html

Answer (score 0):

The solution can be found in internet connection, it is being interrupted that other components cannot be donwloaded.